# How to gracefully stop reading gRPC stream and disconnect on client C#

Tags: c#, grpc

I have gRPC service define like below

```
service ConsumerService 
{
    stream Message Consume(SubscriptionRequest);
}
```

Client looks like this:

```
var consumer = new ConsumerService.ConsumerServiceClient(<channel>);
AsyncServerStreamingCall<Message> proxy = consumer.ConsumeAsync(subRequest));

while (!gracefulShutdown)
    await proxy.ResponseStream.MoveNext(cts.Token);

// todo: tell the server that client is not going to read responses anymore..
await proxy.ResponseStream.CompleteAsync(); // I would like to have method like this
```

I need client to gracefully stop reading responses when gracefulShutdown is set to true.
How do I do this?

If i just stop reading and close channel, server considers it is as abort.

Answer (score 0):

As much as i checked on internet i didnt found any way to do it gracefully. I expected to use CancellationTokenSource. Just use try, catch. Looks like this is intended behaviour. Comment from grpc team

> Cancellations are to be used for forcing termination
>   of outstanding calls due to unexpected circumstances, you shouldn't rely on
>   them for handling the basic workflow in your application

Use catch block like here to check exception

```
catch (RpcException e) when (e.Status.StatusCode == StatusCode.Cancelled)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Streaming was cancelled from the client!");
}
```

More info on github [C# Clean Cancellation](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/8277)